# Material Design WordPress Theme cant change top bar color

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a material design WordPress theme that I downloaded.

It did not have the colors that I liked so I edited the .css file and was changing colors around. I got all the colors right but not the top bar.

You can see the purple top bar here:

www.beerportfolio.glass

I played around with inspect element on chrome and got the bar to change color with this:

```
.inverse.navbar {
    background-color: #E2AD13;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.84);
}
```

But I think something is overriding that in css, cause it doesn't take when I actually edit the real css file and upload it.

I even tried with !important tags as you can see in the full css below:

```
/*
Theme Name: MaterialWP
Theme URI: http://materialwp.com
Author: Brad Williams
Author URI: http://braginteractive.com
Description: Material Design WordPress Theme
Version: 0.0.3
License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Text Domain: materialwp
Tags: right-sidebar, fluid-layout, responsive-layout, custom-menu, full-width-template, sticky-post, theme-options, translation-ready

This theme, like WordPress, is licensed under the GPL.
Use it to make something cool, have fun, and share what you've learned with others.

MaterialWP is based on Underscores http://underscores.me/, (C) 2012-2014 Automattic, Inc.

Resetting and rebuilding styles have been helped along thanks to the fine work of
Eric Meyer http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/index.html
along with Nicolas Gallagher and Jonathan Neal http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/
and Blueprint http://www.blueprintcss.org/
*/

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
>>> TABLE OF CONTENTS:
----------------------------------------------------------------
1.0 Reset
2.0 Typography
3.0 Elements
4.0 Forms
5.0 Navigation
    5.1 Links
    5.2 Menus
6.0 Accessibility
7.0 Alignments
8.0 Clearings
9.0 Widgets
10.0 Content
    10.1 Posts and pages
    10.2 Asides
    10.3 Comments
11.0 Infinite scroll
12.0 Media
    12.1 Captions
    12.2 Galleries
--------------------------------------------------------------*/

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
1.0 Reset
--------------------------------------------------------------*/


/*--------------------------------------------------------------
2.0 Typography
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
body,
button,
input,
select,
textarea {

}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    clear: both;
}

p {
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}

b,
strong {
    font-weight: bold;
}

dfn,
cite,
em,
i {
    font-style: italic;
}

blockquote {
    margin: 0 1.5em;
}

address {
    margin: 0 0 1.5em;
}


pre {
    background: #eee;
    font-family: "Courier 10 Pitch", Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 1.6;
    margin-bottom: 1.6em;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 1.6em;
}

code,
kbd,
tt,
var {
    font-family: Monaco, Consolas, "Andale Mono", "DejaVu Sans Mono", monospace;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

abbr,
acronym {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #666;
    cursor: help;
}

mark,
ins {
    background: #fff9c0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

sup,
sub {
    font-size: 75%;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

sup {
    bottom: 1ex;
}

sub {
    top: .5ex;
}

small {
    font-size: 75%;
}

big {
    font-size: 125%;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
3.0 Elements
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
hr {
    background-color: #ccc;
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}

ul,
ol {
    margin: 0 0 1.5em 3em;
}

ul {
    list-style: disc;
}

ol {
    list-style: decimal;
}

li > ul,
li > ol {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 1.5em;
}

dt {
    font-weight: bold;
}

dd {
    margin: 0 1.5em 1.5em;
}

img {
    height: auto; /* Make sure images are scaled correctly. */
    max-width: 100%; /* Adhere to container width. */
}

figure {
    margin: 0;
}

table {
    margin: 0 0 1.5em;
    width: 100%;
}

th {
    font-weight: bold;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
4.0 Forms
--------------------------------------------------------------*/


/*--------------------------------------------------------------
5.0 Navigation
--------------------------------------------------------------*/

.form-control-wrapper .form-control, .form-control, fieldset[disabled] .form-control:focus, .form-control-wrapper .form-control:focus, .form-control:focus, fieldset[disabled] .form-control.focus, .form-control-wrapper .form-control.focus, .form-control.focus {
    padding: 0;
    float: none;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    background: transparent;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #757575;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
5.1 Links
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
a {
    color: #337ab7;
}

a:visited {

}

a:hover,
a:focus,
a:active {
    color: #3f51b5;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
5.2 Menus
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
.main-navigation {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

.main-navigation ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.main-navigation li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.main-navigation a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.main-navigation ul ul {
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.5em;
    left: -999em;
    z-index: 99999;
}

.main-navigation ul ul ul {
    left: -999em;
    top: 0;
}

.main-navigation ul ul a {
    width: 200px;
}

.main-navigation ul ul li {

}

.main-navigation li:hover > a {
}

.main-navigation ul ul :hover > a {
}

.main-navigation ul ul a:hover {
}

.main-navigation ul li:hover > ul {
    left: auto;
}

.main-navigation ul ul li:hover > ul {
    left: 100%;
}

.main-navigation .current_page_item > a,
.main-navigation .current-menu-item > a,
.main-navigation .current_page_ancestor > a {
}

/* Small menu */
.menu-toggle {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .menu-toggle,
    .main-navigation.toggled .nav-menu {
        display: block;
    }

    .main-navigation ul {
        display: none;
    }
}

.site-main .comment-navigation,
.site-main .paging-navigation,
.site-main .post-navigation {
    margin: 0 0 1.5em;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.comment-navigation .nav-previous,
.paging-navigation .nav-previous,
.post-navigation .nav-previous {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.comment-navigation .nav-next,
.paging-navigation .nav-next,
.post-navigation .nav-next {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    width: 50%;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
6.0 Accessibility
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Text meant only for screen readers */
.screen-reader-text {
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
    position: absolute !important;
    height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.screen-reader-text:hover,
.screen-reader-text:active,
.screen-reader-text:focus {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    clip: auto !important;
    color: #21759b;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: auto;
    left: 5px;
    line-height: normal;
    padding: 15px 23px 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    top: 5px;
    width: auto;
    z-index: 100000; /* Above WP toolbar */
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
7.0 Alignments
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
.alignleft {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1.5em;
}

.alignright {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 1.5em;
}

.aligncenter {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
8.0 Clearings
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
.clear:before,
.clear:after,
.entry-content:before,
.entry-content:after,
.comment-content:before,
.comment-content:after,
.site-header:before,
.site-header:after,
.site-content:before,
.site-content:after,
.site-footer:before,
.site-footer:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

.clear:after,
.entry-content:after,
.comment-content:after,
.site-header:after,
.site-content:after,
.site-footer:after {
    clear: both;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
9.0 Widgets
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
.widget {
    margin: 0 0 1.5em;
}

/* Make sure select elements fit in widgets */
.widget select {
    max-width: 100%;
}

/* Search widget */
.widget_search .search-submit {
    display: none;
}

.widget ul {
    padding: 15px;
    margin-left: 0;
}

.widget-area ul li {
    list-style: none;
}

.widget .textwidget, .widget #calendar_wrap, .widget .tagcloud, .widget .form-search {
    padding: 15px;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
10.0 Content
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*--------------------------------------------------------------
10.1 Posts and pages
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
#primary {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    -ms-word-break: break-all;
     /* Be VERY careful with this, breaks normal words wh_erever */
     word-break: break-all;
     /* Non standard for webkit */
     word-break: break-word;
    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    -moz-hyphens: auto;
    hyphens: auto;
}

.sticky {
    display: block;
}

.hentry {
    margin: 0 0 30px;
}

.byline,
.updated:not(.published) {
    display: none;
}

.single .byline,
.group-blog .byline {
    display: inline;
}

.page-content,
.entry-content,
.entry-summary {
    margin: 1.5em 0 0;
}

.page-links {
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 0 1.5em;
}

.entry-meta span, 
.entry-footer span  {
    margin-right: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.entry-meta span:last-child, 
.entry-footer span:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}

.entry-meta span a, 
.entry-footer span a {
    color: #777;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 90%;
}

.entry-meta span a:hover,
.entry-footer span a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.entry-meta span i,
.entry-footer span i {
    color: #777;
    font-size: 80%;
}

.entry-footer .edit-link {
    float: right;
}

.entry-container {
    padding: 35px;
}

.entry-container h1{
    margin-top: 0;
}

.entry-container h1 a{
    color: #404040;
}

.entry-container h1 a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #3f51b5;
}

a.read-more {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #404040;
    font-weight: 500;
}

a.read-more:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #3f51b5;
}

.card {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.23),0 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.16);
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: 0;
}

.card .entry-img {
    background-color: #F4F4F4;
}

.site-footer {
    background-color: #374147;
    padding: 40px 0;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.site-footer a {
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.site-footer a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 1;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
10.2 Asides
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
#secondary {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    -ms-word-break: break-all;
     /* Be VERY careful with this, breaks normal words wh_erever */
     word-break: break-all;
     /* Non standard for webkit */
     word-break: break-word;
    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    -moz-hyphens: auto;
    hyphens: auto;
}

.blog .format-aside .entry-title,
.archive .format-aside .entry-title {
    display: none;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
10.3 Comments
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
.comment-content a {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

.bypostauthor {
}

.comments-area {
    padding: 35px;
}

.comments-title, .comment-reply-title {
    padding-bottom: 9px;
    margin: 40px 0 20px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

ol.comment-list {
    list-style:none;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.comment-author .avatar {
    margin-right: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    padding: 4px;
}

.comment-meta {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.comment-details {
    overflow: hidden;
    zoom: 1;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.comment-details .reply {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.comment-date a {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #777;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#commentform #comment {
    width: 100% !important;
}

#commentform #submit {
    position: relative;
    padding: 8px 30px;
    border: 0;
    margin: 10px 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.84);
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow .28s cubic-bezier(0.4,0,.2,1);
    transition: box-shadow .28s cubic-bezier(0.4,0,.2,1);
    outline: 0!important;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.23),0 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.16);
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow .28s cubic-bezier(0.4,0,.2,1);
    transition: box-shadow .28s cubic-bezier(0.4,0,.2,1);

    color: rgba(0,0,0,.84);
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: #ccc;
}

#commentform #submit:hover{
    color: #333;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    border-color: #adadad;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
11.0 Infinite scroll
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Globally hidden elements when Infinite Scroll is supported and in use. */
.infinite-scroll .paging-navigation, /* Older / Newer Posts Navigation (always hidden) */
.infinite-scroll.neverending .site-footer { /* Theme Footer (when set to scrolling) */
    display: none;
}

/* When Infinite Scroll has reached its end we need to re-display elements that were hidden (via .neverending) before */
.infinity-end.neverending .site-footer {
    display: block;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
12.0 Media
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
.page-content img.wp-smiley,
.entry-content img.wp-smiley,
.comment-content img.wp-smiley {
    border: none;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* Make sure embeds and iframes fit their containers */
embed,
iframe,
object {
    max-width: 100%;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
12.1 Captions
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
.wp-caption {
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.wp-caption img[class*="wp-image-"] {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.wp-caption-text {
    text-align: center;
}

.wp-caption .wp-caption-text {
    margin: 0.8075em 0;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
12.2 Galleries
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
.gallery {
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}

.gallery-item {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100%;
}

.gallery-columns-2 .gallery-item {
    max-width: 50%;
}

.gallery-columns-3 .gallery-item {
    max-width: 33.33%;
}

.gallery-columns-4 .gallery-item {
    max-width: 25%;
}

.gallery-columns-5 .gallery-item {
    max-width: 20%;
}

.gallery-columns-6 .gallery-item {
    max-width: 16.66%;
}

.gallery-columns-7 .gallery-item {
    max-width: 14.28%;
}

.gallery-columns-8 .gallery-item {
    max-width: 12.5%;
}

.gallery-columns-9 .gallery-item {
    max-width: 11.11%;
}

.gallery-caption {
    display: block;
}


.inverse.navbar {
    background-color: #E2AD13 !important;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.84) !important;
}

.panel-warning>.panel-heading {
    background-color: #E2AD13;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with following css

```
.navbar-inverse.navbar {
    background-color: #E2AD13 !important;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.84);
}
```

Comment: Awesome, what was I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to don't use !important. Instead of that you can change the specificity. If you are interested in how it works, take a look at: http://specificity.keegan.st/

```
.site-header .navbar {
    background-color: #E2AD13;
}
```